# How to plot different themes by passing themes as arguments of a function in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I referred some articles of passing function as an argument and I hope I could then produce plots with different themes by using ggplot2. The following 2 functions could plot correctly:

```
# plot data    
dat <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), 5000), ]

gplot1 <- function(FUN = theme_bw) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(carat, price))+
    geom_point(aes(colour = color))+
    FUN()
}
gplot1(theme_gray)

gplot2 <- function(FUN) {
  theme_set(FUN)
  ggplot(dat, aes(carat, price))+
    geom_point(aes(colour = color))
}
gplot2(theme_bw())
```

But how could I plot with different themes by one function call? 
I tried gplot1() and got nothing, while I tried gplot2() I got warning messages and without any plot:

```
themes1 <- c(theme_bw, theme_gray)
for(i in themes1) gplot1(i)
# nothing

themes2 <- c(theme_bw(), theme_gray())
for(i in themes2) gplot2(i)
# warning messages and without any plot
```

Could anyone enlighten me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `for(i in themes1) print(gplot1(i))`

Comment: I read Marco Sandri's answer first, I tried "for(i in 1:length(ps)) print(ps[[i]])" and got what I need, then I just noticed your comment and I think your code is more concise than mine, thanks you both a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply`:

```
ps <- lapply(themes1, gplot1)
ps[[1]]
```

[image]

```
ps[[2]]
```

[image]